# Lose internet connection if I plug into a second switch

Tags: networking, home-networking, switch

I have a Calix 844G-1 modem (fiber) with the Wi-Fi disabled. The ethernet cables are plugged into a TP-Link 16-port switch (model TL-SG1016DE), and the rest of the house is wired from there. These two devices are pretty much factory default, other than me changing the default admin password.

Last night, we completely lost internet connectivity, but all lights were blinking green. I monkeyed with everything, but in the end I couldn't figure out what had gone wrong and was forced to hit the reset button on both the TP-Link and Calix devices. Now, things are mostly working - except in my home office where I have more devices than wall plugs. I had things plugged into a simple (non-managed) 5-port switch (TP-Link TL-SG105) (I also tried a Comtrend GS-7305 with the same results). If I plug my Windows PC directly into the wall, it works fine. If I plug the PC into the switch and then that is plugged into the wall, Windows loses internet connectivity. --This is not limited to Windows devices, either. I tested my AmpliFi Wi-Fi device and it said it couldn't get an IP address, either.

Does anyone know what could be the problem, or how I can go about diagnosing it? I'll be fine for a few days with just my primary PC having internet access, but at some point I'm going to need to be able to get my internet working for the other devices.

*Edit: I had implied I was using two switches in my home office, which isn't the case. What I meant was that I had need of a smaller, 5-port switch in my office and swapped out the one I was using for an alternative, in case it was specific to the one I had. This has been corrected.*

Comment: Do the link LEDs light up? If not you need a crossover cable/adapter (connecting MDI-X to MDI-X without Auto MDI-X on either side).

Comment: All lights were green, just nothing was getting an IP addr.

Comment: You seem to say you have *all* the ethernet jacks on the Calix plugged into the TP 16-port switch. Is this true?

Comment: so was everything working yesterday with the switch in line in your office? or is that a completely new separate thing?

Comment: If you do have all ethernet cables plugged in from the modem into the switch, then you quite likely have a bridge loop. Unless you are bonding the connections, you should only have 1 connection between them.

Comment: @Yorik I only have 3 of the 4 outgoing jacks on the Calix plugged into the TP, but I am not familiar with what a "bridge loop" is. I'll look into that. I had just been assuming it would increase our internal bandwidth (although, since it's a GB fiber, and I have GB wiring... I don't know what kind of improvement I thought I'd see).

Comment: @Bib See my comment to Yorik.

Comment: @FrankThomas It had happened very rarely before, but seemingly became permanent after I needed to reset the world.

Comment: @Bib (one quick internet search later...) lol, ok, yeah. That's exactly what I did. I'll try just unplugging the others and see if that clears everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas you could try:

- Did you reset the switches in your home office too, or just the ones you mentioned? You could try that.
- If you have two different switches in the home office, and non of those are working, than it’s unlikely that both of those developed a fault. Something else is going on.
- You could try to log in to the management interfaces of both the main switch and the ones in your home office, and look around the settings. Just resetting the devices doesn’t necessarily clear the settings, so if there are some setups, it may be causing the problem. If you have reset all your devices, some of them might have cleared its settings, and some of them might have retained them, and this might cause inconsistencies compared to the setup before the resets.
- Look at the vlan settings on all switches! vlan settings are a strong suspect, and can cause such problems! The switches in your home office might expect a different vlan than the ones set on your central switch.
- You could also try to take a PC and one of the switches from the home office into another room, and try to plug them in there. Or plug them directly into the main switch, or the modem itself. Either they will work or not, but the information may give you further clues about the nature of the problem.

**Edit:**

A few more things you could try:

- You’re right. The switch in your home office, the TP-Link TL-SG105, is an unmanaged switch, indeed. So, the vlan settings might not be the issue here. At least not in the way I thought. It’s still worth checking though whether all the ports on the main switch are in the same vlan.
- If you log in to the central switch, check the state of the port that goes into your home office. Is it up/down? What’s the error rate? Is it set to a certain speed (1 G or 100 Mbps?), or is it set to automatic? If it’s set to automatic, does it set itself to the speed you expect?
- Your central switch also has cable diagnostic features. Run the cable diagnostics. Maybe it’s a cable issue.
- Do the above two things both with the PC plugged in at the other end, and then with the 5-port switch plugged in. Is there a difference in the results?

Comment: * The switches in my home office are simple switches, there's no reset button.
* I'll double-check the managed devices' settings, paying special attention to any VLAN settings.
* I'll also try plugging directly into the main switch.

Comment: I added some more things you could try and check.

Comment: @moswald Did you manage to find the problem in the end? If yes, what was it?

Comment: I never could figure out what was wrong with plugging into my 5-port unmanaged switches. I "fixed" the problem by moving one device to my wifi (I'd prefer ethernet but the wifi is fast enough for what that device needs) and moving another device to another room with an unused wall outlet. Unfortunately I just don't have the expertise or time to debug the problem. 

Answer (score 0):

Did you have explicit VLAN tagging on the network segment your machine was on, and your machine is still specifying a VLAN in its adapter options but post-reset the switches are now running 'flat'? (you'd know if you configured this).

Did you have a different network subnet configured previously, or any of the smart management features enabled on the SG1016DE? Any MTU adjustments?

Personally on my home network I use VLANs but apply them to switchports so the devices do not need to be VLAN-aware or configured to tag their traffic.

That you mentioned that suddenly all devices lost connectivity although the hardware appeared to remain powered, but not everything was working properly after resets, also makes me wonder whether you suffered a utility mains brownout or ESD/lightning strike on the incoming supply which partly fritzed your networking kit. I run all my network and machines from UPSes to mitigate this (when I lived more rurally, I lost too much equipment too often to brownouts and brief blackouts).

Does the simple five-port switch work directly connected between two machines you know to be able to communicate to each other? Is there a specific port on the larger switch which has perhaps defaulted to an uplink or VLAN/trunked port, which needs configuring back to untrunked/untagged, in order to pass traffic from your PC?

If you run Wireshark on your PC while connecting it through your normal network setup, do you see *any* incoming traffic from other devices or router?